# Keras LSTM masking multidimensional array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, masking

My data is sequential 3D array that have different length, something like this (this is just an example data, not my real data):

```
data1 = [
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [1,-2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [-1,2,0]
          ]
        ]

data2 = [
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [1,-2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [-1,0,3],
           [1,2,0]
          ]
        ]
```

So I use padding to even the length of the data by padded all the array to the length of the longest array, which is (3,3)

```
data1 = [
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [1,-2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [-1,2,0]
          ],
          [
           [-99,-99,-99],
           [-99,-99,-99],
           [-99,-99,-99]
          ]
        ]

data2 = [
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [1,-2,3],
           [1,0,-3],
           [1,-2,0]
          ],
          [
           [-1,2,3],
           [-1,0,3],
           [1,2,0]
          ]
        ]
```

My question is, what is the right `mask_value` value in the `Masking()` layer? The whole `[-99,-99,-99]` or just `-99`? Or maybe even changing the masking number?

This is the model built :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=n, input_shape=(None,3)))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(label_total, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

EDIT : I tried using both value, `-99` return loss with NaN value and `[-99,-99,-99]` works fine on training, but really bad at testing. I guess it is because the model didnot avoid the masking value. Any suggestions on how to mask this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`masking` layer documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking), your data should be structured in the format `samples x timesteps x features`.  You can of course extend the concept of `timesteps` to whatever form of sequential information you're using.

You would assign your masking value like below.

```
data[SHORT_DATA_INDEX, MISSING_SEQUENCE_INDICES, :] = MASKING_VALUE
```

I would also consider using an `[embedding layer][2]` which can take care of this problem in a simpler and more elegant way (automatically supporting `0` padding).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Max Feinberg! But I am a bit confused about the masking value assign, could you please explain the variable you are using?

Comment: You can use essentially what ever value you want.  If you were dealing with  a single dimensional feature (which does not seem to be the case), you should be sure to use a value outside of what is present in your data.  The embedding layer by default uses a value of `0.` for masking (indicating skips).

Comment: Yes, I know about that, that's why I use ```-99``` as the padding value and not ```0.``` because the number exists in the data

Comment: If you're using features that are more than just 1 number, you can still `0.`

Comment: If i use ```0.``` as the padding value, the model will skip the ```0.``` value in my data too right? ```0.``` in my data actually represented something too.